# Dynamically added radio inputs does not trigger ng-show

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show

Okay guys, here is my problem:

I have to make list of categories which show only elements of that category when selected ( and hide rest ). I have decided to go with radio buttons / every category has its own radio button.

Code for adding categories is next:

**APP.js**

```
controller('FamiliesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.families = ['All', 'Stark', 'Lannister'....];
    $scope.selfamily = {selfam: 'All'};
}).
```

**HTML**

```
<form ng-controller="FamiliesCtrl"> 
    <input type="radio" ng-model="selfamily.selfam" ng-repeat="family in families" ng-value="family" name="selfam">    
</form>
```

And I am trying to trigger ng-show in html which has next code:

```
<div id="characters" class="row col-xs-9" ng-controller="CharacteresCtrl">
        <div class="character col-xs-3" ng-repeat="character in characters | orderBy:sortParameter | limitTo: 120" char-image="{{character.picture}}" ng-show="selfamily.selfam === '{{character.house}}' || selfamily.selfam === 'All'">
               <h1>{{character.name}}</h1>
        </div>          
</div>
```

Okay, now. This doesn't work BUT if I insert categories manually in this format:

```
<input class="checkboxHidden" id="first" type="radio" name="selfam" ng-model="selfamily.selfam" value="All">
    ... and so on...
```

***IT DOES WORK.*** Your help would be much appreciated. If I need to provide any more code, please let me know.

Just to sum up, dinamically/programatically added category does not have any power on ng-show while manually added works just fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need interpolation to access the value of character.house.  This should work:

```
ng-show="selfamily.selfam === character.house || selfamily.selfam === 'All'"
```

...

Looking closer at your code, the values set by your radio buttons exist in a different controller than the list of characters.  You'll have to use a single controller for all values, or use a service to share values between controllers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that is not a solution for my problem. I have changed that and everything is the same.. Problem must be somewhere in dinamically adedd radio buttons but I can't figure out where, they get created properly - every radio button get proper value but they simple doesn't want to trigger ng-show when value ( family ) === character.house

Comment: Two controllers were the problem. Thank you very much!